# Neo4j server plugin: disable String escaping

Tags: java, json, rest, plugins, neo4j

I have written a Neo4j server plugin and want to return a JSON string. Using `String` as return type will cause Neo4j to escape the string.
The [plugin documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html) refers to `org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Representation` as valid return type next to primitives, Neo4j types and `String`.

Unfortunately I am not able to extends this abstract class in order to build an own representation class, since its abstract methods are package private and can not be overridden.
One can easily create an instance of the class using `Representation.emptyRepresentation` but there is no setter for the value afterwards.

Did anyone manage to return a JSON value from a server plugin without escaping yet?

Answer (score 0):

Using [unmanaged extensions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html) you have the the full control over result format, content types, headers etc.

Unmanaged extension do not enrich the standard REST API, instead the provide new REST endpoints. JAX-RS annotations give you full control here.

Comment: This is also an interesting approach, but to be honest I do not like the Neo4j documentation here, neither for managed nor unmanaged extensions. It seems to me, that they did it just to have it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Representation` classes always seemed a bit strange to me, too. I had similar trouble with getting my data out of my Server Plugin. I ended up writing a my own version of a `MappingRepresentation` to be able to represent the values I required. Perhaps this was not necessary and there are appropriate facilities within Neo4j I just did not notice. The code I wrote is not complete in regards of mapping values that can occur in JSON, but those should be easily added. Additionally, it's probably not the most performant code out there. I just needed this `Representation` class and it works well for me.
You find the code at https://gist.github.com/khituras/81f909271b8b81ddc375

I hope it works for you.

Comment: I get the idea how to use serializer to build an own representation class from looking at your code, but I will jump into in more detail shortly, thank you!